# why does the loop execute just one time?

Tags: c, for-loop, scanf, undefined-behavior

I would like to know why the loop below just execute one time?
Here is my code.

```
for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
{
    printf("name:");
    gets(student[i].name);
    printf("math score:");
    scanf(" %d",student[i].math);
    fflush(stdin);        
}
```

Comment: Does your program terminate normally, or with an error?

Comment: Please provide a complete, reproducible example.

Comment: Well, with the [gets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/10871073) call and [fflush(stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979209/10871073), even running the loop once is most likely once too often. ;(

Comment: Probably `gets(student[i].name);` writes out of bounds and so overwrites `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At  least the code contains a typo. You have to write

```
scanf(" %d", &student[i].math);
            ^^^
```

Also this call

```
fflush(stdin);
```

has undefined behavior.

And the function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard. Instead use function `fgets` or `scanf`.

Comment: Are you sure that the `math` member is not an `int *` or array?

Comment: @mch Yes, I am sure. It is the reason that his loop breaks.:)